# How to communicate between two VB.NET applications over the network

Tags: vb.net

I am programming in VB.NET.

I would like to sent a String or an Integer from a VB.NET application to another VB.NET application on different computers.

I looked at some tutorials, but all the tutorials work only on the local network, and I want it to work over the Internet.

This is my code for local connections:

```
Dim Listener As New TcpListener(34349)
Dim Client As New TcpClient
Dim Message As String = ""


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                        Handles Timer1.Tick

    If Listener.Pending = True Then
        Message = ""
        Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient()
        Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Client.GetStream())
        While Reader.Peek > -1
            Message = Message + Convert.ToChar(Reader.Read()).ToString
        End While
        RichTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black
        RichTextBox1.Text += Message + vbCrLf
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                          Handles btnsend.Click

    If txtName.Text = "" Or cmbAddress.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("All Fields must be Filled", _
                        "Error Sending Message", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        Try
            Client = New TcpClient(cmbAddress.Text, 34349)
            Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
            Writer.Write(txtName.Text & " Says:  " & txtmessage.Text)
            Writer.Flush()
            RichTextBox1.Text += (txtName.Text & " Says:  " & txtmessage.Text) + vbCrLf
            txtmessage.Text = ""

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
            Dim Errorresult As String = ex.Message
            MessageBox.Show(Errorresult & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please Review Client    Address", "Error Sending Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

`txtmessage.text` is the string I want to send.

`txtName.Text` is just a name of the sender

`cmbAddress.text` is the [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) of the remote computer

How can I send data to another remote computer in VB.NET?

Comment: look at some socket examples, that works over the internet, unless you have the port blocked

Comment: Will both applications always be located on the same computers (or on a shortlisted number of computers) or you are looking for a communication betweeen two programs in two different random computers?

Comment: Sounds like a server to me

Comment: If you use a protocol like TCP or UDP it makes no difference if the network is a local one or the internet or whatever.

Comment: I tried to use tcp server and client but it work only on local network

Comment: If the target computer is always the same, you can access it via its IP address (as you do when navigating through internet). But this computer has to be "opened to internet" to allow to do so. You have to define your problem better, post the code you tried, tell the exact conditions, and why it didn't work/the error you got.

Comment: If this program will be ran by an explicitly defined list of computers on a LAN, then all you have to do is look into basic socket programming. If, however, this program is expected to be ran by computers whose IP address may be unknown to you or by computers across a WAN/the internet, then you'll have to take this a step further and create a server that accepts and relays data to its intended destination.

Answer (score 5):

What you are talking about is creating a client-server application. There are a few different ways you can do this.

The easiest way would be to have your programs talk to a web application or web service. Basically you will create a site that your programs will connect to and send data, or have it check for data on a scheduled interval. For this you would need to use some sort of database to hold the updates until the client requests them.

The second option is way more complex and utilizes socket connections. You will basically use sockets to connect to the program running on a certain port on the remote machine. Your program will need to have a send class to send the data as well as a listener class to wait for incoming connections. You will also have to keep in mind that you will need to opens up the incoming ports on both local firewall. Due to firewall issues, and the complexity of setting up socket connections, this is a far more advanced option.